# What are the lebesgue - measurables sets of $[0,1[$

Tags: measure-theory

I am trying to prove that a function defined on $[0,1[$ is lebesgue - measurable, but I am not sure about the lebesgue - measurables sets on $[0,1[$

Comment: What is your definition of "Lebesgue measurable subset of $E$", where $E$ is some given subset of ${\mathbb R}?$

Comment: The basis for the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra are sets of the form $[a,b],[a,b),(a,b],(a,b)$ for $0\leq a,b\leq 1$.